# How to expand mobile app to app for tv (android)?

Tags: android, google-play, android-tv

I'm trying to expand my application to make it available on TV. I did as they say in this guide [Getting Started with TV Apps](https://developer.android.com/training/tv/start/start.html)

Here is my **Manifest**:

```
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.software.leanback"
    android:required="false" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen"
    android:required="false" />


<application
    android:name=".NetworkAccess.MyApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:banner="@drawable/banner"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="Amazon Codes"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <activity
        android:name=".StartActivity"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".TvActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|navigation"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Leanback"
        android:logo="@drawable/banner" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LEANBACK_LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

I also added a folder `layout-w960dp` in `res` in which i created layout for TvActivity. But when I update my application in the store, it is still not available for TVs.

What's my mistake?

Comment: Did you check [TV app quality](https://developer.android.com/develop/quality-guidelines/tv-app-quality.html) guide by Google? I don't know if it's necessary but "Only apps that meet the following quality criteria will qualify as an Android TV app on Google Play."

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a new module in the project for Android TV.
Same is for Wear.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a new module my friend.
Your project structure should look like this:

[image: Project Structure]

As you see I have a core module too. In the core you can put all the code that is shared between the two modules (usually utils, constants, networking stuff and so on).

After that, your settings.gradle should have the new modules specified like this:

```
include ':app', ':core', "tv"
```

Comment: what about the package name? How will it look in the store? Will there be 2 different applications?

Comment: [Distribute on TV](https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/launch/distribute-tv.html)

Switch to advanced mode in the Developer Console to see the tv options.

You can use the same package name.

Basically you will have 2 apks submitted to the store, each one available to the devices supported. The tv one will be visible to Android TV devices and the other one to mobile devices.

Comment: It can be done so that the store would see one apk, but this apk could be used for both TV and phone?

Comment: I really don't know if it is possible honestly. If you have a multimodule project in Android Studio you can see that when you try to export a signed apk it will ask you if you want to do that for the tv or for the app. My guess is that you have to do different apks.